# reading attr class, but I need only one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that has many classes. I select them all with

```
$('#mydiv').attr('class');  //outputs 'redball blueball greenbrick whitesquare'
```

What I actually need is the class that starts with 'red' so I really want to output only 'redball'. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Usually, you'd split the string via `String.split(" ")` and then loop through the array of matches to find the class you're looking for. I'm sure there's a quicker way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like has already been said, split on spaces and find your matching class.  Here's an example function:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $('#mydiv').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (/red.*/.test(list[i])) {
      alert(list[i]);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to extract it with a regular expression:

split the output into an array an while itreating the array values try to test with some regulr expression (like this: /red[a-zA-Z09]*/)

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `.hasClass()` method to help you decide.

```
if( $( '#myDiv' ).attr( 'class' ).hasClass( 'redball' ) ) { 
    // call method to serve the redball...
}
```

Alternatively, using `.split()` and regex as suggested by the others can also work -- depends on how you want to use your output.

**BONUS:**
But for efficiency sake, it's better to cache the DOM object in a local variable and access that if you need to do more with the element. This is so that Javascript doesn't have to go back to the DOM tree and fetch the same object every time you want to use it.

```
var myDiv = $( '#myDiv' ); // store the <div> object in the variable
var classNames = myDiv.attr( 'class' );

switch( classNames ) {
    case 'redball':
        serveBall( 'red' );
        break;
    case 'blueball':
        serveBall( 'blue' );
        break;
        .....
}
```

Comment: hassClass assumes that I know the name of the class. In this case I don't. I just know that there's a red something. It could be redball, redsquare, redbrick, etc. So I'm trying to select the 'red' to know what type it is 'ball','square', etc.

Comment: @jarn, then yeah, regex is the way to go then.